# Dependency Inversion principle breaks when interface implementation has more methods than the interface?

Tags: java, solid-principles

I want to know how can I call a method in a class without breaking the dependency Inversion principle?

In the example below if I have an interface called the `Animal` like:

```
interface Animal {
     void walk();
}
```

and, its Implementation like :

```
public class Bird implements Animal{
     public void walk() {
          //Do Something
     }

     public void fly() {
         //Do Something
     }
}
```

I want to execute the `fly()` method, my code currently looks like this which breaks the dependency Inversion principle.

```
public class Start {

  private Bird bird;

  @inject
  public Start(Bird bird) {
     this.bird = bird;
     this.bird.fly();     // THIS BREAKS DEPENDENCY INVERSION
  }

}
```

How can I accomplish this without adding `fly()` in the interface or creating a new interface for Birds?

Comment: Dependency Inversion is not broken by calling the `fly` method. It is broken by storing the variable `private Bird`. Bird is a concrete class; and concrete classes cannot be member variables or fields, according to the DIP.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
interface IMovable {
    void move(int distance);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class Bird implements IMovable {
    @override
    public void move(int distance) {
        if(distance > 5) {
            walk();
        } else {
            fly();
        }
    }

    public void walk() {
         //Do Something
    }

    public void fly() {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Start {

    private IMovable animal;

    @inject
    public Start(IMovable animal) {
       this.animal = animal;
       this.animal.move(100);
    }
}
```